# What difference will GTK3 support make for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, gtk

Emacs 24 is said to come with GTK3 support. What difference will this make (for the users)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function wise none (except it might be easier to use for people with disabilities) but esthetically it's a little bit better. I don't know of any drawbacks when it comes to GTK3.

http://batsov.com/articles/2011/08/19/a-peek-at-emacs24/ here is a good list of the new features.

Screenshot of Emacs 24 (GTK3):

[image: Screenshot of Emacs 24 (GTK3)]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how it's function-wise the same, maybe you have a reference you could link? Also, maybe you could provide screenshots of how it looks better? Maybe a comparison to GTK2?

Comment: I have none. I can't see why it would make a significant difference to users if Emacs use GTK3 instead of GTK2. It's better in most ways and it does look better but it's nothing revolutionary since it doesn't add new functionality. Unless GTK3 is easier to use for people who are blind or have some other disability i guess.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please include the new information by incorporating it in your answer instead. It will be easier to find for people visiting this question then and it will make it a better answer.

Comment: Done. The first screenshot i showed you wasn't even GTK3! It wasn't released 2009 like the URL said :) There's probably a lot of new functions in Emacs 24 that's just under the hood.

Comment: Is release date sufficient to know that a screenshot is emacs with GTK3 and not any other GTK version? In a former comment you mentioned that Emacs with GKT3 is better in most ways, which are these way? In short, I'd appreciate more substance in your answer if that is possible.

Comment: GTK3 was first released February 2011 so the answer is yes. I'm not saying Emacs itself is better with GTK3. GTK3 is only an improvement over GTK2 and that is it. I've edited my first response and added a good link that shows new features and the few minor GTK related enhancements.